# Windows batch script to move files

Tags: windows, batch-file, move

I need to move files from one directory to another in windows, and I need to write this in a batch script.

We have written a SQL job where backup files will be created every 4 hours on the `D:` drive and last 4 backup files will be saved and others will be deleted.

I need to write a batch script to move these files from the `D:` drive to the `E:` drive every 10 hours.

Can anyone help me to write this script.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a Q&A site. Try some code, and come back if you have questions.

Comment: Hint: try `move /?` and `schtasks /?`

Comment: Hi I know the move command move Source Destination. But i need the command to move files every 10hours

Comment: For that, have you tried `schtasks /?` ?

Answer (score 16):

Create a file called MoveFiles.bat with the syntax

```
move c:\Sourcefoldernam\*.* e:\destinationFolder
```

then schedule a task to run that MoveFiles.bat every 10 hours.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly how it worked for me. For some reason the above code failed.

This one runs a check every 3 minutes for any files in there and auto moves it to the destination folder. If you need to be prompted for conflicts then change the /y to /-y

```
:backup
move /y "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Camera Uploads\*.*" "D:\Archive\Camera Uploads\"
timeout 360
goto backup
```

Answer (score 6):

```
move c:\Sourcefoldernam\*.* e:\destinationFolder
```

^ This did not work for me for some reason

But when I tried using quotation marks, it suddenly worked:

```
move "c:\Sourcefoldernam\*.*" "e:\destinationFolder"
```

I think its because my directory had spaces in one of the folders. So if it doesn't work for you, try with quotation marks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

`:backup
 move C:\FilesToBeBackedUp\*.* E:\BackupPlace\
 timeout 36000
 goto backup`

If that doesn't work try to replace "timeout" with sleep.
Ik this post is over a year old, just helping anyone with the same problem.