# Windows Batch Script to move all files from one directory to another in windows, and folder contains spaces

Tags: windows, move

Very similar to

[Windows batch script to move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968949/windows-batch-script-to-move-files)

and the solution was...  for drives "c" and "e"

```
move c:\Sourcefoldername\*.* e:\destinationFolder
```

However, this is moving all files inside Dropbox's "Camera Uploads" and the file path contains a space.

I can't rename the file, as Dropbox creates a new one, and foils our objective.

I attempted wrapping it with double quotes... but this also fails...

```
move "C:\Users\USERNAME\Dropbox\Camera Uploads\*.*" D:\dropboxBU
```

Thank you for insight... on this 2015 MLK day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
move "C:\Users\USERNAME\Dropbox\Camera Uploads\"*.* D:\dropboxBU
```

Comment: It also must be noted that the target file must exist, as the move command does not create it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

xcopy  %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Camera Uploads D:\dropboxBU\ /e /r /y

run from command line, will copy all files, overwrite any with same name and won't prompt you